# Compare 2 lists and apply rules

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list of possible strings:

ListOfPossibleStrings

- String1
- String2
- String3
- String4
- String5
- String6
- String7
- String8
- String9
- String10

ListOfScenario1Strings

- String2
- String4
- String7
- String8

ListOfScenario2Strings

- String3
- String9
- String10

I can select any combination of the items in ListOfPossibleStrings to add to another list.. lets call it ListOfSelectedStrings.

However, I need to call different functions in these scenarios based on whats in the ListOfSelectedStrings

**Scenario 1**

If the ListOfSelectedStrings contains ONLY any of the strings in ListOfScenario1Strings - Call function HidePage();

**Scenario 2**

If the ListOfSelectedStrings contains ONLY any of the strings in ListOfScenario2Strings - Call function ShowPageConditional();

**Scenario 3**

If the ListOfSelectedStrings has a combination of any string from ListOfScenario1Strings and ListOfScenario2Strings) and/or contains String1, String5, String6 call function ShowPageMandatory();

I'd thought something, like this might have worked for scenario 1 but then it 'could' include any other string as it doesnt exclude the other strings.

```
if (ListOfSelectedStrings.Any(x => ListOfScenario1Strings.Any(y => y.StringValue == x)))
{
    HidePage();
}
```

Comment: As complicated as your logic is, I think I would go RBAR (row by agonizing row). That might be the only sure fire way to get all the conditional logic right.

Comment: The `SequenceEquals()` method might help.

Comment: maybe `l1.All(x => l2.Contains(x));`

Comment: Also, I suggest that whatever solution you choose, that you spend a lot of time constructing unit tests that hit the three "happy paths" that you describe, plus all of the other reasonable combinations that you can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make 3 lists

List1 
List2
List3

```
bool anyList1 = ListOfSelectedStrings.Any(x => List1.Any(y => y.StringValue == x));
bool anyList2 = ListOfSelectedStrings.Any(x => List2.Any(y => y.StringValue == x));
bool anyList3 = ListOfSelectedStrings.Any(x => List3.Any(y => y.StringValue == x));
```

Then deal with the logic

```
if(anyList3) ShowPageMandatory(); 
else if (anyList1 && anyList2)  ShowPageMandatory();
else if (anyList1 && !anyList2 && !anyList3) HidePage();
else if (anyList2 && !anyList1 && !anyList3) ShowPageConditional();
```

And consider HashSet
It has subset, superset, and overlaps

[HashSet Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: While I appreciate there are many different ways of doing this and I appreciate the RBAR approach, this is the one which works best for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ `Except` method to get the results you're looking for.

- When you use `Except`, the result is everything in first list *except* what's in the second list
- Putting `Any` on the end of that tells you there's something in the result, so there's something in the first list that wasn't in the second list
- Then you can negate the result, so you know everything in the first list was in the second list

These should give you the correct results for each of your three scenarios:

```
if (!ListOfPossibleStrings.Except(ListOfScenario1Strings).Any())
    HidePage();

if (!ListOfPossibleStrings.Except(ListOfScenario2Strings).Any())
    ShowPageConditional();

if (!ListOfSelectedStrings.Except(
         ListOfScenario1Strings.Union(
             ListOfScenario2Strings.Union(
                 new List<string> { "String1", "String5", "String6" }))).Any())
{
    ShowPageMandatory();
}
```